# prompting a user input for both rows and columns in my Checkerboard? (Java Programming)

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to prompt a user input for my rows and columns for my checkerboard with a dialog box (J option something?)

// Displays an 8 by 8 grid of red and black rectangles

```
import javax.swing.*;  // For JFrame and JPanel
import java.awt.*;    // For Color, Container, and GridLayout

public class checkerboard{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();
        theGUI.setTitle("Checkerboard");
        theGUI.setSize(300,300);
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = theGUI.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
        Color color1 = Color.black;
        Color color2 = Color.red;
        for (int i = 1; i<= 64; i++){
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            // Alternate colors on a row
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                panel.setBackground(color1);
            else
                panel.setBackground(color2);
            pane.add(panel);
            // At the end of a row, start next row on the other color
            if (i % 8 == 0){
                Color temp = color1;
                color1 = color2;
                color2 = temp;
            }
        }
        theGUI.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: I need help prompting user input with a dialog box for my rows and columns

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried messing around with JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Comment: Post your code and explain where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: It's already up, I can't really explain where i'm stuck however since I don't know where to place it.

Comment: Where's the code you tried for using the `JOptionPane`

Comment: You don't have any code relating to user input in your code that you posted, so we don't know what you have tried, or what you are even going for.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: JFrame checkerBoard = new JFrame();
         checkerBoard.setSize(500,500);
         checkerBoard.setTitle("CheckerBoard"); //Title
         checkerBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         String rows = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of rows"); // 2/9/16 
         int row = Integer.parseInt(rows);
         
         String columns = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of columns"); //User input for columns 
         int col = Integer.parseInt(columns);

Comment: ^ it's a start right now

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
columns = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of columns"));
```